# how to insert data in React js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I am facing an issue with React JS , i want to do show all the data in a row not in a column.

What should I change in my code?

Working demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wood-9jrib?file=/src/App.js:0-355

react component

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const names =
    data &&
    data.length &&
    data.map(({ full_name }) => <p key={full_name}>{full_name}</p>);

  return <div className="row">{names}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Just use a `span` tag with some space instead of `p` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` : is being used as paragraph so it will cover whole width by default, until unless you override with css

You can use,

```
// if you need more space you can apply class to span and add some padding-mrgin
// as per your need
<span key={full_name}>{full_name} {' '}</span>
```

in place of

```
<p key={full_name}>{full_name}</p>
```

[image: Edit lucid-sun-vrkjb]

Comment: plz create an example code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: @MHasan, yes sure

Comment: how should i match row data  to column ? plz (@)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi]

Comment: @MHasan, Sorry didn't get you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-mountain-6yu6r?file=/src/App.js , like this?

Comment: thanks [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)

Comment: but i facing another problem [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2349407/vivek-doshi)